# SD card Size not reading properly (Debian Linux)

Tags: linux, debian, micro-sd-card

I have a MicroSD card that has 128M printed on the card, however when I ran a command to check, it always shows up as a 7.4G drive with a 119M Partition, I get the same result whether I'm using fdisk or lsblk.

The microSD card came shipped with a USB Rubber Ducky from the Hak5 Shop, I don't think they would do anything shady... but I'm inherently paranoid already so...

I would like to hear if anyone else knows why this would be occurring?

Comment: Is there anything else, like a brand name, printed on the card?

Comment: @DanielB, No actually, there's nothing on there except the generic MicrosSD logo and 128MB and a small arrow showing the proper direction to insert the card. 

Like this one: [Link](http://g02.a.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1OINxIXXXXXavXXXXq6xXFXXXK/Memory-Card-font-b-128MB-b-font-font-b-micro-b-font-font-b-sd-b.jpg)

On the back however there is a VERY faint set of characters (Looks like a serial, but it's mostly unreadable)